# Not able to create nested Object in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I am having the List Of Objects with parent child reference

```
case class EmployeeLevel(id: Long, name: String, parentId: Long,
                         item: List[EmployeeLevel])

val employeeList = List(
  EmployeeLevel(1L, "Manoj", 0L, Nil),
  EmployeeLevel(2L, "Sv", 1L, Nil),
  EmployeeLevel(3L, "Cp", 2L, Nil),
  EmployeeLevel(4L, "Manju", 3L, Nil))
```

How to create Tree Structure or  arrange them in a hierarchical Order Like

```
val employeeList = List(
  EmployeeLevel(1L, "Manoj", 0L, List(
    EmployeeLevel(2L, "Sv", 1L, List(
      EmployeeLevel(3L, "Cp", 2L, List(
        EmployeeLevel(4L, "Manju", 3L, Nil))))))))
```

or This is the final json that i should get

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Manoj",
        "parentId": 0,
        "item": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Sv",
                "parentId": 1,
                "item": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Cp",
                        "parentId": 2,
                        "item": [
                            {
                                "id": 4,
                                "name": "Manju",
                                "parentId": 3,
                                "item": [  ]                         

                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried with this:

```
 def arrange(employee1:List[EmployeeLevel],accumulator:List[EmployeeLevel]): List[EmployeeLevel] ={
    @tailrec   def arrange1(employeeLevel:List[EmployeeLevel],accu:List[EmployeeLevel]):List[EmployeeLevel] ={
      if(employeeLevel.nonEmpty){
        val headd=employeeLevel.head
        val taill=employeeLevel.tail
        val tt=taill.filter(_.parentId==headd.id)
        val qq= List(headd.copy(item = tt))
        arrange1(taill,accu++qq)
      }else{
        accu
      }

    }
    arrange1(employee1,Nil)
  }
```

But its working for only one level

Comment: Would be nice to add what you've already tried, or it will look like a "how would you do it for me" question.

Comment: The code you've posted seems fine. What's the problem?

Comment: i want to get required result  by using recursion or reduce function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick

```scala
object App {
  case class EmployeeLevel(id: Long, name: String, parentId: Long,
    item: List[EmployeeLevel])

  val employeeList = List(
    EmployeeLevel(1L, "Manoj", 0L, Nil),
    EmployeeLevel(2L, "Sv", 1L, Nil),
    EmployeeLevel(3L, "Cp", 2L, Nil),
    EmployeeLevel(4L, "Manju", 3L, Nil),
    EmployeeLevel(5L, "foobar", 2L, Nil),
    EmployeeLevel(6L, "barfoo", 42L, Nil))

  def main(args : Array[String]) {
    val nestedEmployees = createNestedEmployeesList(employeeList)

    println(nestedEmployees)
  }

  def createNestedEmployeesList(employees: List[EmployeeLevel]): Iterable[EmployeeLevel] = {
    val children = employees.groupBy(_.parentId)

    val rootNodes = findRootNodes(employees)

    rootNodes.flatMap(createChildrenList(_, children))
  }

  def createChildrenList(id: Long, children: Map[Long, List[EmployeeLevel]]): List[EmployeeLevel] = {
    children.get(id) match {
      case Some(employees) => 
        employees.map(employee => employee.copy(item = createChildrenList(employee.id, children)))
      case None => Nil
    }
  }

  def findRootNodes(employees: List[EmployeeLevel]): Set[Long] = {
    val parentIds = employees.map(_.parentId).toSet
    val nodeIds = employees.map(_.id).toSet

    parentIds &~ nodeIds
  }
}
```

The algorithm gives you the following output

```
List(EmployeeLevel(1,Manoj,0,List(EmployeeLevel(2,Sv,1,List(EmployeeLevel(3,Cp,2,List(EmployeeLevel(4,Manju,3,List()))), EmployeeLevel(5,foobar,2,List()))))))
```

Comment: This only works if all the the employees have a common ancestor (`0L` in this case). If there are multiple root nodes you will lose some employees. You could define a `findRoots` function, filter the employee list, apply your `createChildrenList` to every root nodes and then flatten the results.

Comment: Thank You.This is working fine..and in my case the base parent will be having parent id 0L

Comment: Thanks @Marth, you're right. I've updated my solution to also work for the general case :-)

Comment: Glad that I could help :-)

Comment: Nice solution. I think within `createChildrenList` you can simplify `employees.map {
          case EmployeeLevel(id, name, parentId, _) =>
            EmployeeLevel(id, name, parentId, createChildrenList(id, children))
        }` To something like `employees.map(_.copy(item = createChildrenList(id, children))`

Comment: You're right @mattinbits, it's much nicer :-) I've updated my answer accordingly.