# Unable to create nested object from three level mappings in Scala

Tags: java, scala, recursion

Here are my entities.

```
case class Entity(id: Long, name: String)

/**
 * entityId is the FK of Entity Table PK
 */
case class Parameter(id: Long, entityId: Long, type: Long, name: String)

//type => 1 = Input, 2 = Output

/**
 * parameterId and sourceParameterId are the FK of Parameter Table PK
 */
case class Source(id: Long, parameterId: Long, sourceParameterId: Long)
```

Example data:

```
Entity(1,"Agriculture")
Entity(2,"Factory")
Entity(3,"Customer")
Entity(4,"Institute")
Entity(5,"Student")

Parameter(1,1,2,"Raw Food")
Parameter(2,2,1,"Raw Food")
Parameter(3,2,2,"Packed Food")
Parameter(4,3,1,"Packed Food")
Parameter(5,4,2,"Knowledge")
Parameter(6,5,1,"Knowledge")

Source(1,2,1)
Source(2,4,3)
Source(3,6,5)
```

Desired Output

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Agriculture",
        "item": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Factory",
                "item": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Customer",
                        "item": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Institute",
        "item": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Student",
                "item": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32112411/3301316) but failed to achieve, since I don't have self reference entities.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this : http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-create-json-strings-from-scala-objects

Comment: Can you show the complete code sample? I cannot see any correlation yet between your case classes and the following piece of JSON.

Comment: @Roman , I updated the question with comments on top of case classes

Comment: @Jet: Do you have any other code? Where's the logic which transforms case classes to JSON?

Comment: @Roman , my question is not how to convert into Json(even I have that code using Json4s) I am looking for the structure like that as in the form of Json (may be Case class)

Comment: To me it's unclear what you want to achieve, I think you should give more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your classes to something like

```
case class Entity(id: Long, name: String)
case class Parameter(id: Long, entity: Entity, type: Long, name: String)
case class Source(id: Long, parameter: Parameter, sourceParameterId: Long)
```

, `play-json` (it can be used outside of Play) works perfectly.